# New Widget are not showing

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I added a new sidebar according to WordPress Codex and for some reason it shows only on the admin and nothing shows on my front pages..

I tried to look for it on Google and here on the forums but I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using Sahifa theme which has it's own "theme-functions.php".
It doesn't work if i add it to the 'functions.php'.

Here is my code-

```
<?php
function arphabet_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Header Widget Area',
        'id' => 'home-header-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="arphabet">',
    ));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
?>
```

And on my 'header.php'-

```
<div id="header-widget">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home-header-1' ); ?>
</div>
```

I added a banner widget to my sidebar through the admin panel but nothing shows..

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please link to the page on the Codex you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks, that's where i looked- http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes
and i made few modifications according to what i found on google/forums

Answer (score 1):

If you register a new sidebar widget area in a child theme, use this code in your child themes functions file:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Header Widget Area',
    'id' => 'home-header-1',
    'description' => __( 'Your Widget Description.', '$text_domain' ),
) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Brad, i found my problem it's a little embarrassing..
I noticed in my code that the div i created for the widget isn't showing and then i found out it was on an elseif and not also on the if itself so now it works :)

Comment: No worries @Neit. Please mark this as a useful answer and/or upvote. Thanks